# Thymeleaf pagination only partially working

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, thymeleaf

I tried to paginate my users CRUD, but it doesn't work. I can open users.html, it only shows 3 records, which is fine and if I use localhost:9001/users/page/1, 2 etc manually, it works fine. But the paginator under the table is an error screen.

My UserController:

```
@GetMapping("users/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable (value="pageNo") int pageNo, Model model) {
        int pageSize = 3; //only 3 so I can easily test it
        
        Page<User> page = userService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize);
        List<User> listUsers = page.getContent();
        
        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);
        return "/users";
    }

**and** 

@GetMapping("/users")
    public String viewHomePage (Model model) {
        //model.addAttribute("listUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
        return findPaginated(1, model);
    }
```

My UserService:

```
Page<User> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize);
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
@Override
    public Page<User> findPaginated(int PageNo, int PageSize) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(PageNo -1, PageSize);
        return this.userRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

UserResository extends JpaRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
```

Pagintation in users.html:

```
 <div th:if="${totalPages > 1}">
            <div class="row col-sm-10">
                 <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <!--Total Rows: [[{$totalItems}]]
                </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}">
            valami
                <a th:if="${currentPage != i}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                <span th:unless="${currentPage != i">[[${i}]]</span> &nbsp; 
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-1">
            <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}}">Következő</a>
            <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Következő</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/page/' + ${totalPages}}">Utolsó</a>
            <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Utolsó</span>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Even if I comment out this part of the html, the error is still displayed.

Errors:

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//users.html]")
Could not parse as expression: "{$totalItems}" (template: "/users" - line 132, col 24)
```

Summary:
displaying only 3 records - works
using url's like /users/page/2 - manually works
displaying the numbers and pages under the table - does not work

Answer (score 0):

Well, `{$totalItems}` should be `${totalItems}` (which is causing your parser level error).  This will continue to cause a parser error regadless of if it is commented out or not unless you use [Thymeleaf's parser-level comment blocks](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#thymeleaf-parser-level-comment-blocks) which look like this:

```
<!--/* Total Rows: [[{$totalItems}]] */-->
```